# ScrollViewer + ScrollBar arrows

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When user clicks on the scroll bar arrow, the content shifts very slow(horizontal offset changes on 16). How can I increase the speed of shifting when I click on arrows?
(SmallChange doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's quite hard-coded in the scroll viewer.

The only way I know of, is to make a new panel based on the panel that you want to use in the scroll viewer, and implement `IScrollInfo` for it.

Then, setting this panel as the content of the scroll viewer and setting `CanContentScroll` to true.

`StackPanel` implements `IScrollInfo` but other panels do not.